# Saving two different models in same controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am posting to my `OrdersController#create` action and in that I'm trying to do two things: save an `Account` and an `Order`.  The `Order` is being saved, but the `Account` is not and I don't know why not.

#### OrdersController

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # other actions removed

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
    @order.email = current_user.email
    @order.address = current_user.address
    #@order.created at = @line_items.created_at
    @account = Account.where(user_id:current_user.id)
    @previous_balance = Account.previous_balance_for_user(current_user)
    @account = Account.new(
      user_id: current_user.id,
      email: current_user.email,
      debit: @cart.total_price,
      acctbal: @previous_balance - @cart.total_price
    )
    @account.save
    respond_to do |format|

      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil

        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Thank you for your 
              order.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: 
                      :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type, 
                                    :datefor)
    end
end
```

#### Account

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :order
  validates :depotype, :credit, presence: true
  DEPOSIT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]
  validates :depotype, inclusion: DEPOSIT_TYPES

  def self.previous_balance_for_user(user)
    where(user_id: user.id).order(:created_at).pluck(:acctbal).last || 0.0
  end
end
```

#### Relevant log section

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-28 21:54:52 -0400
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√",     
 "authenticity_token"=>"jYKMts1Zwgl4a0Y+ud86J3mAh0rGHuDqW0rUqSm45NQ=", 
"order"=>{"name"=>"dddd"}, "commit"=>"Place Order"}
 User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Cart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts"  WHERE "carts"."id" = ?
 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
 LineItem Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"  WHERE  
"line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 3]]
 (0.0ms)  SELECT "accounts"."acctbal" FROM "accounts"  WHERE  
"accounts"."user_id" = 1  ORDER BY "accounts"."created_at" ASC
Menu Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "menus".* FROM "menus"  WHERE "menus"."id" = ?  
 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("address", "created_at", "email",  
 "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["address", "3494 dsfsdf dr.
  valdosta, GA 31504"], ["created_at", "2015-04-29 01:54:52.414099"],
 ["email", "parent@example.com"], ["name", "dddd"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-
  29 01:54:52.414099"]]
 SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "line_items" SET "cart_id" = ?, "order_id" = ?,  
 "updated_at" = ? WHERE "line_items"."id" = 3  [["cart_id", nil], 
 ["order_id", 3], ["updated_at", "2015-04-29 01:54:52.417100"]]
(93.0ms)  commit transaction
Cart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts"  WHERE "carts"."id" = ? 
LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
LineItem Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"  WHERE
"line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 3]]
SQL (0.0ms)  DELETE FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ?  [["id", 3]]
(83.0ms)  commit transaction
 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
 Completed 302 Found in 238ms (ActiveRecord: 178.0ms)


 Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-28 21:54:52 -0400
 Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  
 [["created_at", "2015-04-29 01:54:52.632112"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-
 29 01:54:52.632112"]]
(76.0ms)  commit transaction
 Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
 User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  
 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 Completed 200 OK in 1109ms (Views: 1028.1ms | ActiveRecord: 77.0ms)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You've asked about the `create` action of your `OrdersController`, and yet the log you're showing is the `index` action of your `StoreController`.

Comment: i dont know why it does that... i just pressed the check out again and that log entry regenerated itself again. so this means its using that method in store controller?? i look in there and there is nothing. ill update the post with its content

Comment: Well, the opening line of your `new` action in `OrderController` has a redirect to `store_url` `if @cart.line_items.empty?` - so I'm guessing that's probably happening and that's mapped to the `/`. I'd put some logging in that conditional to confirm, and then turn your attention to why the cart is empty.

Comment: strange i commented the whole if statement and still goes to store controller

Comment: Right, it redirects there at the end of the `OrdersController#create`. We can see that now that you're showing the actual log for the `create` action.

Comment: I'm just going to clean up your question now.

Comment: Ok, so now I can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Very obviously your `@account.save` is failing because of a validation error.  Your validations in `Account` are:

```
validates :depotype, :credit, presence: true
validates :depotype, inclusion: DEPOSIT_TYPES
```

...and yet you don't provide either `:depotype` nor `:credit` in your controller code.

The big mistake here though is that you don't check the return from `@account.save` in your controller code, if it returns false (which I'm sure it is) then your code ignores that and proceeds as if nothing is wrong.

You should almost always check the return when `.save`ing a model.

Another option, especially when you're providing all the data for the model in your code (ie. you're not getting that data from the user), is to use the `.save!` method (with the `!`) which will raise an exception if there's a validation error.  Then you can correct that.

Comment: ahhhh  i see, how would i redo the validation such that the credit page will require a depotype but not when we have a debit entry? that ! helped i can see the errors

Comment: There are a number of different ways to have conditional validations, you should probably [read the guide on validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), for where you are in your Rails I think you'll benefit a huge amount from that and the other guides.